# Conversion among struct types with unexported fields

Tags: go, type-conversion

From the [specs on conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions), I read

> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:
>
> - [..]
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), x's type and T are not type parameters but have identical underlying types.
> - [..]

From the above specs, I would have expected the following code to compile

```
package main

import "github.com/fxtlabs/date"

type Date struct {
    day int32
}

func main() {
    _ = date.Date(Date{12345})
}
```

However, it does not compile with error message

`cannot convert Date{…} (value of type Date) to type date.Date`

Note that `"github.com/fxtlabs/date".Date` is defined [here](https://github.com/fxtlabs/date/blob/master/date.go#L71) as

```
type Date struct {
    // day gives the number of days elapsed since date zero.
    day int32
}
```

Why does it fail to compile? Is it because the field `day` from `"github.com/fxtlabs/date".Date` is unexported? If yes, shouldn't this be specified in the specs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because the field day from "github.com/fxtlabs/date".Date is unexported?

Yes.

> If yes, shouldn't this be specified in the specs?

It is in the spec under [Type Identity](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_identity).

> Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical types, and identical tags. **Non-exported field names from different packages are always different.**

In other words, the underlying types are NOT identical because their fields are **unexported**.

Example of identical types `struct {Day int32}` (packag a) and `struct{Day int32}` (package b).
Example of NOT identical types `struct {day int32}` (packag a) and `struct{day int32}` (package b).